# Ajax Post only working when debugging in browser

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, post

I've checked every similar question on here, the solutions and more, but still can't find a solution that works for me.

First: I'm absolutely new to Ajax and just got a project to fix from some developer that isn't reachable anymore, so I'm at my wits end...

Basically, this is the code-snippet for the Link that is clicked, which action works perfectly fine when I debug the whole process and just "step-over" everything, but simply running it will always end it in error instead of success.

```
var serviceURL = "http://address";
function bestellePosition(token, artikelId, userId, menge) {
    var authheader = 'Bearer ' + token;
    var url = "/WarenkorbPositions/AddMengeToCart";
    var type = "POST";

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: type,
        url: serviceURL + url,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authheader); },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            userId: userId,
            artikelId: artikelId,
            menge: menge
        }),        
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.result === true) {
                alert('it worked');
            } else {
                alert('it didnt work');
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result.result);
        }
    });
}
```

Additional things I tried were adding  `dataType: "json",` , which seemingly didn't do anything.
Adding a `timeout: 10000` which also didn't seem to do anything.
Just sending the data as `data: {...}` instead of using `JSON.stringify` which didn't work at all.

EDIT:
URL-Method

```
private PostXnameEntities db = new PostXnameEntities();
private String conStr = @"Server=xxx\SQLEXPRESS,xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;UID=xxx;Password=xxx;";

public Boolean AddMengeToCart(int userId, int artikelId, decimal menge)
        {
            var positionen = db.WarenkorbPosition.Include(w => w.Artikel).Include(w => w.User);
            var posquery = from p in positionen where p.UserId == userId && p.ArtikelId == artikelId select p;

            WarenkorbPosition pos = new WarenkorbPosition();

            if (posquery.ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                pos = posquery.ToList().First();
                if (menge == 0)
                {
                    int rows = 0;

                    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conStr);

                    string queryOrder = "DELETE FROM [PostXname].[dbo].[WarenkorbPosition] WHERE [UserId] = @UserId And [ArtikelId] = @ArtikelId";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryOrder, sqlConn);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelId", artikelId);
                    try
                    {
                        sqlConn.Open();
                        rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }
                    sqlConn.Close();

                }
                else
                {
                    decimal posMenge = pos.Menge.Value;
                    decimal MengeGesamt = posMenge + menge;
                    int rows = 0;

                    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conStr);

                    string queryOrder = "UPDATE [PostXname].[dbo].[WarenkorbPosition] SET [Menge] = @Menge WHERE [UserId] = @UserId And [ArtikelId] = @ArtikelId";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryOrder, sqlConn);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelId", artikelId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Menge", Convert.ToDecimal(MengeGesamt));
                    try
                    {
                        sqlConn.Open();
                        rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }
                    sqlConn.Close();

                }


            }
            else
            {

                int rows = 0;
                SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conStr);

                string queryOrder = "INSERT INTO [PostXname].[dbo].[WarenkorbPosition]([UserId],[ArtikelId],[Menge])VALUES(@UserId,@ArtikelId,@Menge)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryOrder, sqlConn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelId", artikelId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Menge", Convert.ToDecimal(menge));
                try
                {
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
                sqlConn.Close();

            }



            return true;
        }
```

Comment: @JaredSmith I just changed the language in those without checking for syntax errors before posting them here. In the original file there is no unescaped single quote. I adjusted the original post.

Answer (score 0):

can you check the below code and try once.
can you also check the the url method u mentioned is a GET or POST type
Please also tell what u got in result in error method (result.result)

```
 var serviceURL = "http://address";
  function bestellePosition(token, artikelId, userId, menge) {
    var authheader = 'Bearer ' + token;
    var url = "/WarenkorbPositions/AddMengeToCart";
    var type = "POST";

    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: type,
      url: serviceURL + url,
      beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authheader); },
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        userId: userId,
        artikelId: artikelId,
        menge: menge
      }),
      success: function (result) {
        if (result.result === true) {
          alert('it worked');
        } else {
          alert('it didn\'t work');
        }
      },
      error: function (result) {
        alert(result.result);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Mention what's new here!

Comment: I posted the URL-Method as an edit to the original post (I changed some variablenames to omitt some information, but it should still make sense).

result.result throws "undefined".

From what I can see you only added `dataType; "json",`, as I said above, I already tried that. I still copied your whole code and added it after commenting the previous function, though it didn't change anything.

Comment: try using console.log(result) in both success and error. I think the return from server is not coming here.

Comment: `Object { message: "OK computer", result: true, client: "erpfrontend" }` comes up on success. `Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(), … }` comes up on error...